# virtualenv, mysql-python, pip: anyone know how?

Tags: python, mysql, virtualenv, easy-install, pip

I'm trying to install the mysql bindings in a virtualenv.  I'd prefer to use pip or easy_install.  pip gives me the following error:

```
  File "setup_posix.py", line 24, in mysql_config

    raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))

EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

easy_install either gets a 404 from sourceforge or gives me a very similar error.

Does anyone know how to get around this in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I'm also trying to setup MySQL bindings in a virtualenv. All I had to do was install the package that contains mysql_config. On Ubuntu it's called `libmysqlclient-dev`.

After that I was able to do a (virtualenv'd) `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install`.

Comment: In order to make this work I also had to install python-dev before doing the setup.py build and install.

Comment: After libmysqlclient-dev I used PIP to install the mysql binding:
"pip install MySQL-python"

Comment: Comment by anonymous user:  On Fedora it's called `mysql-devel`, i.e. `sudo yum install mysql-devel`. After that, `pip install mysql-python` works in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 7):

In OS X I had used Macports to install my MySQL, which made the `mysql_config` file be called `mysql_config5`.

So I did:
`sudo ln -s mysql_config5 /opt/local/bin/mysql_config`

And then ran `pip install MySQL-python` from a virtualenv and all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have mysql_config at all if you don't have the appropriate mysqlclient-dev OS package installed.

Personally, for packages that require extensive C compilation, I prefer to install OS-packaged versions, as I've had fewer problems that way. It's easier to install the OS-packaged version of mysql-python on all my servers than it is to install the compilation dependencies.

Fortunately in my experience those packages also tend to be very stable (mysql-python, PIL, lxml, etc), so I don't need to version-pin them per-project.

It does, however, prevent me from using virtualenv --no-site-packages, which is a little annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It is failing to find mysql_config.  Put the directory containing mysql_config on your path and try again.

Comment: For me, the command to do that was: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql-5.5.24-osx10.6-x86_64/bin` on MAC OSX.  Your mileage may vary, but just do a `locate mysql_config` and you should be in business.