# -bash: virtualenv / django-admin: command not found

Tags: python, django, bash, terminal, virtualenv

I have installed virtualenv and I'm trying to create a new environment and the following error occurs.

```
tukey:env juanzinser$ virtualenv general
-bash: virtualenv: command not found
```

I'm not sure is a virtualenv problem since the same goes on trying to create a new django project.

```
tukey:env juanzinser$ django-admin startproject mysite
-bash: django-admin: command not found
```

Not sure if it's a permission issue (I have admin rights though), because both virtualenv and django are correctly installed.

```
tukey:env juanzinser$ pip install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in      /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-13.1.2-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
tukey:env juanzinser$ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Comment: Check your path. Bash cannot find the executable.

Comment: The directory containing `virtualenv` and `django-admin` are not in your `PATH` ..use full path instead or make an alias or include the directories in the `PATH`

Comment: See also: [virtualenv, mysql-python, pip: anyone know how?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1511661/55075)

Answer (score 0):

Check for the location of the virtualenv by:

```
which virtualenv
```

and then try to run virtual environment with the complete path.Like when I do this, here is what I get.

```
$ which virtualenv
$ /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

then run it like

```
/usr/local/bin/virtualenv general
```

Comment: If `which virtualenv` works, `virtualenv` would work, too. Which is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with you. but I figure out. You just use
Fisrt: You need to find where the django-admin file, then use `flexible connection command.`

Example:

> find / -name django-admin

/usr/local/python3.5.0/bin/django-admin

> ln -s /usr/local/python3.5.0/bin/django-admin  /usr/bin/

Comment: I wouldn't recommend adding random things into `/usr/bin`. One should rather add `/usr/local/python3.5.0/bin` into `PATH` in their user environment scripts (e.g. `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`).